# Valores de Barras de Cores no Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Eu tenho um código com 3 variáveis: a1, a2 e dc1.A variável dc1 é o valor absoluto da diferença de a2 e a1. Eu estou gerando um gráfico na matplotlib com os valores da variável a1 e gostaria as cores da 'colorbar' fossem definidos pelos valores da variável dc1. Mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Abaixo segue o meu código.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a1 = np.array([1.5,2.5,2.0,5.5,7.0])

a2 = np.array([5.0,7.5,1.0,8,9])

dc1 = np.abs(a2-a1)

idx=np.arange(len(a1))

plt.scatter(idx,a1,s=dc1*100, c=dc1, cmap="BuPu",
            edgecolors="black", linewidth=0.90)
plt.title(" MLP Keras")
plt.xlabel('Amostras\n')
plt.ylabel('Discrepâncias(m)')
plt.colorbar(dc1)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Grato pela atenção

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [documentação](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html), em inglês, o `plt.colorbar` utiliza um `matplotlib.ScalarMappable` como argumento. Esse `ScalarMappable` tem informação suficiente acerca do gradiente e dos valores associados a ele e pode ser construído manualmente através de `mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(args)`.

No seu código você não precisa fazer isso, quando passa um valor para o `cmap` no `plt.scatter` a colorbar já é preparada automaticamente. Para exibi-la a única coisa que precisa ser feita é chamar `plt.colorbar()` (sem argumentos).

a única modificação necessária no seu código é

```
plt.colorbar()
```

e o resultado fica

[image: imagem com o colorbar corrigido]